# Using the negative in French

Tags: négation

Can you say "*Il n'y a aucune de bananes*" or would it be "*Il n'y a aucun de bananes*"?

Would "*aucun*" have to agree with the feminine noun "*banane*"?

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible forms: "il n'y a pas de banane" (singular, "il n'y a pas de bananes" (plural) or "il n'y a aucune banane" (singular). The meaning is different:

- Il n'y a pas de banane

Implies "there is no banana (in this recipe)" or something similar; no banana as ingredient.

- Il n'y a pas de bananes

There are no bananas (here).

- Il n'y a aucune banane

There isn't any banana (here).

Answer (score 0):

No native speaker but your turn "il n'y a aucune de bananes" does not sound idiomatic.
So to a question of the form

> A/ Est-ce qu'il y a des bananes ?

some possible answers include

> B/ Il y en a. Il n'y en a pas.
>
> C/ Il n'y a pas de bananes.
>
> D/ Il n'y a aucune banane.
>
> E/ Il n'y en a aucune.
>
> F/ Aucune.
>
> G/ Oui/Non.
>
> H/ On n'a aucune banane de bonne.

Comment: *Y a-t-il des bananes ?* sounds a better French. But no, sorry, there is none (of them): *il n'y en a aucune*.

Answer (score 0):

*Il n'y a aucune banane* : yes, *aucun* has to agree with the feminine noun *banane* — without the *de* word.

In fact, *aucun* (or *aucune*) has the meaning of *zero* and is used as a number : *il y a une banane*, *il y a deux bananes*, *il y a zéro banane*.

(Or with numbers: *il y a 1 banane*, *il y a 2 bananes*, *il y a 0 banane*).

Except that *aucun*/*aucune* needs a negative prefix (*ne* before a consonant or *n'* before a vowel as here): *il n'y a aucune banane*.

As if *zero* was not enough to say you have no banane :^)